# Trying to rank the distribution of events over time

Tags: probability-distributions

I am trying to figure a way to rank a set of financial trades done across multiple instruments.

This takes place across of a period of 1 year.
For each instrument, there is a list of trades that are either positive or negative.

I am trying to find a way to assign a score to each instrument, where:

- It is desirable that positive and negative trades happen close to each other and may alternate.
- It is undesirable to have a cluster of positive trades and a cluster of negative trades.

For example, if I was ranking the result of each month:

- +-+-+-++--++ would be desirable
- +++++-----++ wouldn't be desirable because of a large sequence of negative results
- +++++++--+++ would be ok, despite large monotonous chunks

I would like to determine a score, as a single number, that will be used to rank each instrument.

What would be a good approach for this?

Comment: Just sum them up, i.e. interpret each plus and minus as +1 and -1 resp. By adding them, you'll see if the result wobbles around a zero without large departures, you're in a desirable case, else you're in an undesirable case.

Comment: @Raskolnikov, but then ++-- and --++ would provide different results since the min would be 0 and -2 respectively